# Immutable Dictionary<TKey, TValue>

Tags: c#, dictionary, immutability

How would you implement constructors for an immutable `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`-like class?

Also, is it possible to allow users to use the syntax:

```
ImmutableDic<int, int> Instance = new ImmutableDic<int, int> { {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3,1} };
```

Comment: That syntax is translated by the compiler to a series of `.Add()` calls. That means a mutable dictionary is required.

Comment: Thank you! So, how would you implement constructors? Perhaps receiving two arrays of the same length as parameters to the constructor?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to write a constructor that accepts a mutable `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Build the mutable dictionary and just pass it to the constructor of your immutable dictionary:

```
var data = new Dictionary<int, int> { {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3,1} };
var instance = new ImmutableDic<int, int>(data);
```

As explained in BoltClock's comment, the initializer syntax can't be used with an immutable dictionary, since it requires an `Add` method.

Answer (score 2):

Have the constructor accept an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

This way, you can do:

```
var Instance = new ImmutableDic<int, int>(
   new Dictionary<int, int> {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3,1} });
```

You can construct with the "minimal" addition of "new Dictionary", and you can also use any other way that is convenient and produces such an enumerable sequence.