# Truly Immutable Dictionary in .NET

Tags: c#, dictionary, immutability

Good morning, afternoon or night,

Still building on my question about [immutable dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427338/immutable-dictionarytkey-tvalue) in .NET, I came up with the following question: while if then `TKey` and `TValue` are value types you can make a dictionary truly immutable, in the sense that neither its inner structure nor the values themselves can change, if those parameters are *reference types* keys and values can easily be changed, thus changing the dictionary itself. Am I right?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're looking for a `ReadOnlyDictionary` implementation, look here: http://bit.ly/ecgwhZ.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If yoo programmed in C, you have a int * const ptr. You would like to have a const int * const ptr. You can't have it in C#, unless your object contract specify the object is immutable.

Comment: A reference type can be immutable aswell, immutability is not peculiar to value types.

Comment: @MattDavey: Yes, a reference type *can* be immutable but it is not *required* to be. The problem Miguel is describing is not that there are no immutable reference types, it's that there *are* mutable reference types.

Comment: @Miguel Just a side note: you probably finished implementing your immutable dictionary by now. But you might be interested in my own immutable dictionary, [`Map<Key,Value>`](http://core.loyc.net/collections/hashtrees.html), which has some unique features and algorithmic properties, and an interesting mutable sibling type, [`MMap<Key,Value>`](http://loyc.net/doc/code/classLoyc_1_1Collections_1_1MMap_3_01K_00_01V_01_4.html).

Answer (score 25):

> if then TKey and TValue are value types you can make a dictionary truly immutable, in the sense that neither its inner structure nor the values themselves can change, if those parameters are reference types keys and values can easily be changed, thus changing the dictionary itself. Am I right?

Not exactly. You've identified a real problem but your characterization of it is not fully thought through.

First off, I note that yes, a value type stuck in an immutable dictionary is immutable, even if it is a mutable value type. Why? Because value types are only mutated by mutating the variable which contains them. If your dictionary does not expose the variables it uses to store the value types then there is no way for those variables to be changed.

However, even if a value type is itself immutable *an immutable value type can contain a reference to a mutable reference type*, and now we've got the same problem. Restricting the dictionary to value types only pushes the problem off a level, it does not solve it!  What you really need to guarantee "deep" immutability is a dictionary of *blittable* value types. By "blittable", I mean a value type with no fields of reference type. (So-called because you can serialize one of these to storage by "blitting" the bits straight out to disk.)

Unfortunately there is no constraint in the generic type system to constrain to blittable value types.

Let's now consider the general problem of mutable reference types  in an immutable dictionary, whether those reference types are there directly or via a field of a value type. What can go wrong if a reference type is mutated out-of-band while it is in an immutable dictionary?

Well, the first thing that comes to mind is that an immutable dictionary should give the same answer twice to the same question twice, and now this is no longer the case. If you say "customers[name].Address" you'd expect to get the same answer twice, but if the customer is a reference type that can mutate, you'll get a potentially different answer. That might or might not be desirable. (And note that *the dictionary* is giving the same answer twice: it's giving the same reference to the customer object. It is actually the customer object that is not giving the same answer twice.)

Assuming you don't try to memoize answers to questions that can change, this is usually not a big problem.

A bigger problem is when an object that is in a hash table as a key mutates, thereby changing its hash value and "losing" the object in the table.

If that happens then someone is not keeping inside the guidelines. The guidelines are (1) reference types should if possible not base their hash codes (and equality) upon data that can mutate, and (2) an object being used as a key in a hash table should not be mutated.

Comment: Is there a concept of blittable types in .NET? I guess you can make one but to the runtime it's no different than a non-blittable type? Also there are many value types in .NET that are mutable, like Point, Size, etc. Do you know if you guys made this decision against the guidelines or was it because the immutability wasn't a consideration in the earlier versions of .NET? Just curious because it could even be because of performance reasons, so I understand.

Comment: @Joan: The runtime does care because pointer types in unsafe code have to be pointers to blittable types. I do not know why Point, etc, are mutable.

Comment: If the runtime does care, wouldn't it be useful to be able to define a type as blittable, meaning it's a struct that only contains other blittable types?

Comment: (This would also make efficient serialization a much easier-to-solve problem for this subset of types)

Comment: It's perfectly fine for an immutable object to hold references to mutable objects if the purpose of those references is to encapsulate only immutable aspects of them (most notably their identity).  For example, if a repair shop kept an immutable list of the VINs of the cars it serviced on a given day, such a list could be used to determine the make and model of the fifth car the shop serviced on that day (since the make and model of a car can never change once it leaves the factory).  It could also be used by the shop to determine if it sees the same car again.  It could not...

Comment: ...be used to determine whether the fifth car was red or blue at the time of the last visit.  Even if one could find that fifth car given its VIN and see that it is now red, and even if the factory could report that the car was red when it was manufactured, there would be no way to determine whether the car might have been painted blue before the last service visit and painted red afterward.  Still, the fact that many aspects of a car are mutable does not mean that an immutable list of cars should not be considered to be "truly immutable".

Answer (score 2):

Structs are value types and are not necessarily immutable - so the answer is no. You can design immutable types (make all fields and properties readonly). However there is no type constraint available (like `where TKey : class`) which would allow you to enforce it.

**Update**: An example:

```
class Bar { public int I; }
struct Foo { public Bar B; }

var b = new Bar();
var f = new Foo { B = b; }

dict[key] = f;
b.I++;
```

A bit constructed I admit.

Comment: You could add a where TKey : ValueType constaint, and then in the constructor query they TKey type for ImmutableAttribute by reflection.

Comment: Unless it is enforced by the compiler you don't really gain that much. I guess you could write a tool which runs as a post-build step and checks whether or not types marked with an immutable attribute are really immutable but it can get tricky pretty fast. Constraining `TKey` to value type does not change that.

Comment: If someone has tagged a class/struct with ImmutableAttribute that should be enough, if their Immutable object isn't actually Immutable, that's their fault. As the author of the dictionary you can't take responsibility for every possible type that it might contain.

Comment: ChrisWue, so what if the value type is mutable? **How is it going to be mutated in the immutable dictionary**? A value type can only be mutated by mutating the *variable* which contains it, and if the immutable dictionary does not expose any of its internal variables to its callers then they have no ability to mutate the value types.

Comment: Mh, but you can break the value type immutability. Admittedly that's only if you care about deep immutability.

    `

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the new BCL Immutable Collections:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx

This is still a preview release but it contains the following types:

- `ImmutableStack<T>`
- `ImmutableQueue<T>`
- `ImmutableList<T>`
- `ImmutableHashSet<T>`
- `ImmutableSortedSet<T>`
- `ImmutableDictionary<K, V>`
- `ImmutableSortedDictionary<K, V>`

I wish the next version of C# will include keywords to specify immutability constraints at the class level (similarly to what is suggested [here](http://madprops.org/blog/immutability-in-csharp-5/)), and a way to clone objects more easily, like [what can be done in F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx) with the keyword `with` :

```
var o1 = new CustomObject { Field1 = 0, Field2 = 3 }
var o2 = o1 with { Field1 = 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very quick design, probably wont compile straight off but hopefully will give you some ideas...

```
[Immutable]
class ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public ImmutableDictionary(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> keysValues)
    {
        // Ensure TKey is immutable...
        if (typeof(TKey).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ImmutableAttribute), false).Length == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Type '{0}' must be immutable.", typeof(TKey).AssemblyQualifiedName);

        // Ensure TValue is immutable...
        if (typeof(TValue).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ImmutableAttribute), false).Length == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Type '{0}' must be immutable.", typeof(TValue).AssemblyQualifiedName);

        foreach(var keyValue in keysValues)
            base.Add(keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value);
    }

    public new void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot modify contents of immutable dictionary.");
    }

    public new void Clear()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot modify contents of immutable dictionary.");
    }

    public new void Remove(TKey key)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot modify contents of immutable dictionary.");
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return base[key]; }
        set
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot modify contents of immutable dictionary.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this:
http://ayende.com/blog/164739/immutable-collections-performance
by the way be completely careful when using ImmutableDictionary

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's going on, drop down to a type simpler than a dictionary: a `List<T>`.  If one creates a `List<T>`, throws some items in it, then creates passes it to the constructor of `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` and destroys all references to that list other than the one contained within the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, then that list will be immutable.  Its state will never change, regardless of whether `T` mutable or immutable, class or struct.  Anyone who would regard such a list as mutable if `T` is a mutable class type fails is mistakenly regarding the list as holding objects.  It doesn't.

**If `T` is a class type, a `List<T>` does not *hold* objects--it *identifies* them.**  If a `List<int[]>` is made immutable as described above, after five `int` array references have been added to it, then as long as it exists it will always hold references to those same five arrays.  The contents of the arrays may change, but **the properties of the objects referred to by a `List<T>` form no part of the list's state**.

The state of a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is a little harder to define than the state of a `List<T>`, especially if one considers the possibilities of muddled states caused by wonky `GetHashCode()` implementations, but the same principles apply.  If `TKey` is a class type, the only aspects of a `TKey` instance which form part of the dictionary's state are the value returned by `GetHashCode`, and the equivalence class implied by its `Equals` method; both of those things are supposed to be immutable.  No legitimately-mutable aspect of a `TKey` or `TValue` class object should be regarded as part of the state of a `TDictionary<TKey,TValue>`.